# Laravel attaching models for many to many relation gives undefined variable error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have a ReleasePackages Model and Artifacts Model and have many to many relation between them.

`ReleasePackages.php` is as given below :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReleasePackages extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
    */
    public function artifacts()
    {
        return $$this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Models\Artifacts',
            'release_packages_artifacts',
            'release_package_id',
            'artifact_id'
        );
    }
}
```

and `Artifacts.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Artifacts extends Model
{
    public function artifact_type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('ArtifactTypes');
    }

    public function release_packages()
    {
         return $$this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Models\ReleasePackages',
            'release_packages_artifacts',
            'artifact_id',
            'release_package_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Now in my controller, I have the following code :

```
$releasePackage = new ReleasePackages();

$releasePackage->package_name = $request->input('name');
$releasePackage->created_by = 1;
$releasePackage->approval_status = 'pending';

$releasePackage->save();
$artifacts = $request->input('artifacts');

$releasePackage->artifacts()->attach($artifacts);
```

It is saving the data in `release_packages` table correctly. But when try to attach relationship, it is giving error :

```
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/var/www/html/maxdev/app/Models/ReleasePackages.php"
line: 15
message: "Undefined variable: {"package_name":"Package","created_by":1,"approval_status":"pending","id":15}"
```

It will be helpful if someone can point out what went wrong here. Or is there any other method for attaching relationships ?

Comment: what is $artifacts variable? what's its content?

Comment: Seems like you are using variable variable syntax on ```$this``` in your models, meaning php will look for a variable named the content of that variable. Remove one $ from ```$$this``` and that should hopefully do it. I can't see how that is intentional from the framework's side.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. I haven't noticed it.. My bad :(